# Several text (equation) appear in single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe with 3 variables: group_name, y, x.
And there are 7 groups in the group_name (= 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

I want to make a single graph with this database, thus I make a script as follows:

```
grp <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group_name))+
geom_point()+
theme_classic()
```

And I also have a dataframe with equations(y~x) for each group.

For example (not real value),

```
feed_name      equation
a              y = 0.02x-0.74
b              y = 0.67x-0.53
c              y = 0.1*exp(x)+1
d              y = 10*log(x)
e              y = 0.1x^2+3
```

I want to represent each equation on the graph.
Unfortunately, some equations are not linear,
thus I cannot using 'stat_regline_equation'.

Could you give me some solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369376/plot-output-of-non-linear-model-output-in-ggplot2

Comment: Do you want to print the text of the equation on the graph or a line following that equation? Or both? Either way, it would help if you shared that data in valid R syntax so it can be easily copy/pasted. `dput(your_sample_data)`, for example, or at least quoting the equations so they can be imported with `read.table`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved it with geom_text() with paste(df$equation, collapse = "\n). But I will try with your solutions. Have a good day : )